# Why is it not allowed to initialize a struct member in the global (file) scope, but it is OK to do it inside a function?

Tags: c

I have a struct declared like this in the global scope of a c file:

```
typedef struct S_t {
    int i;
    char c;
} S_t;

S_t s1;
```

The compiler does no allow me to initialize each member in the global scope, but it is OK to do it inside a function, eg. main():

```
S_t s1 = {5, 'c'};         // This is OK!
S_t s2 = {.i=5, .c='5'};   // OK, designated initialization
S_t s3 = {.c='c'};         // OK, partial designated  initialization
S_t s4;
// s4 = {5, 'c'};          //This is an error. Why?
// s4.i = 5;               //This is also an error.

int main(void) {
    s4.i = 6;              //This is fine..
    return 0;
}
```

I tried using, gcc (C11, C18) as well as g++.
But I always get an error:
gcc: "error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘.’ token"
g++: "error: ‘s4’ does not name a type"

Could someone please explain why is it illegal to assign a value to s4.i in the global scope?

Comment: In C, **all code** must be inside a function. Declarations do not count as code.

Comment: Thems the rules. Pretty much all you can do outside a function is define and initialize. `s4.i = 6;` is an assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a syntactic difference between *initialization* and *assignment*.  The presence of the `=` operator is only part of the story.

Initialization is part of a declaration, and declarations are allowed at file scope.  The presence of one or more *declaration specifiers* (type specifiers like `int` or `float`, typedef names like `S_t`, storage class qualifiers like `static`, type qualifiers like `const` or `volatile`, etc.) tells the compiler that this is a declaration.

Otherwise, the presence of the `=` operator indicates that this is an assignment expression, and assignment expressions may only appear as part of a statement, and statements are only allowed within function bodies.

As for why you can't have statements outside of a function body, well, that's just how the languages C was derived from were designed.

Comment: very precise answer! thanks a lot @JohnBode!

Answer (score 3):

You can only have the constant expression initializations outside the functions.

All code has to be inside the functions.

`s4.i = 6;` is not an initialization, it is an assignment which has to be inside the function body

Comment: “You can only have X outside Y” is ambiguous phrasing in English. It could mean “Each X must be inside Y” or “Anything outside Y must be X.”

Comment: Also, the phrase “constant expression initializations” does not get to the issue. There are no non-constant expressions in this code. The issue is simply that statements (including assignments) cannot be outside of functions; declarations with initializers can be outside of functions.

Comment: And “code” is a generic term; it is not correct, or at least not clear, to say all code has to be inside functions. Declarations and preprocessing directives are also code. The distinction in C is not between code and non-code but between declarations and statements (and preprocessing directives). All statements (not code) must be inside functions.